# Why does Backup and Sync from Google create many directories in temp directory on Windows?

Tags: windows, temporary-files, google-backup-and-sync

I noticed that my computer's drive space is going down. So I researched that and found that its Backup and Sync from Google who is doing that. It creates many directories in local Temp directory and doesnt delete them. Directories names start from "_MEI*****" where asterisks are numbers (e. g. _MEI36482, _MEI39282, _MEI42242). I manually delete them but they appear again. Does anyone know whats going on? This problem happens on 2 of my computers.

If it matters I have 2 Backup_and_Sync_from_Google accounts is use.

[Here is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PpX0K.png)

Comment: Same here. Also using 2 accounts but not sure if that's the cause. I noticed it because my windows login times increased to 15+ minutes! Yes, minutes! It's not only a lot of disk space but it's many many files which is slowing down the login time, I think. (The files in your profile (and temp files are part of that) are being inspected or copied during login. Just as a heads-up for people searching for this problem.)